# FOSElasticaBundle multiple nested query

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

I use FOSElasticaBundle to handle searching. All works great when I have one level of nesting. However, when I have two levels of nesting results which should match the innermost nest are not returned (e.g. searching for 'xx' category does produce results, but searching for 'yy' brand does not - and should).

Here's my fos_elastica configuration:

```
fos_elastica:
clients:
    default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
indexes:
    my_index:
        client: default
        types:
            product:
                mappings:
                    title: { boost: 1 }
                    articleNumber: ~
                    introductionDateSearch: { type: integer }
                    delistingDateSearch: { type: integer }
                    deleted: { type: boolean }
                    category:
                        type: "nested"
                        properties:
                            name: { boost: 1 }
                            brand:
                                type: "nested"
                                properties:
                                    name: { boost: 1 }
                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: MyBundle\Entity\Product
                    provider: ~
                    finder: ~
                    listener: ~
```

And my query handler:

```
public function searchForKeyword($keyword, AbstractUser $user)
{
    $this->setFilters($user);
    $keyword = trim($keyword);

    if ($keyword !== '') {
        $mainQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Bool();
        $mainProductQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Bool();

        //searching in Product title
        $productQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Text();
        $productQuery->setFieldQuery('title', $keyword);
        $productQuery->setFieldParam('title', 'boost', 5);
        $productQuery->setFieldParam('title', 'type', 'phrase_prefix');

        //searching in Product articleNumber
        $articleNumberQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Text();
        $articleNumberQuery->setFieldQuery('articleNumber', $keyword);
        $articleNumberQuery->setFieldParam('articleNumber', 'boost', 5);
        $articleNumberQuery->setFieldParam('articleNumber', 'type', 'phrase_prefix');

        //searching in Category name
        $categoryQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Text();
        $categoryQuery->setFieldQuery('name', $keyword);
        $categoryQuery->setFieldParam('name', 'boost', 3);
        $categoryQuery->setFieldParam('name', 'type', 'phrase_prefix');

        $nestedCategoryProductQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Nested();
        $nestedCategoryProductQuery->setPath('category');
        $nestedCategoryProductQuery->setQuery($categoryQuery);

        //searching in Brand name
        $brandQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Text();
        $brandQuery->setFieldQuery('name', $keyword);
        $brandQuery->setFieldParam('name', 'boost', 3);
        $brandQuery->setFieldParam('name', 'type', 'phrase_prefix');

        $nestedBrandCategoryQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Nested();
        $nestedBrandCategoryQuery->setPath('category.brand');
        $nestedBrandCategoryQuery->setQuery($brandQuery);

        $mainProductQuery->addShould($productQuery);
        $mainProductQuery->addShould($articleNumberQuery);
        $mainProductQuery->addShould($nestedCategoryProductQuery);
        $mainProductQuery->addShould($nestedBrandCategoryQuery);

        $mainQuery->addMust($mainProductQuery);

        $esFilteredQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Filtered($mainQuery, $this->filters);

    } else {
        $esFilteredQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Filtered(new \Elastica\Query\MatchAll(), $this->filters);
    }

    $this->query = new \Elastica\Query();
    $this->query->setQuery($esFilteredQuery);
}
```

How is the `$nestedBrandCategoryQuery` added to the `$mainProductQuery`?

Thanks for your help!
gtb

Comment: Do you have any luck with yur problem? I'll face the same problem and I'd like to know if you manage to find a solution.

Comment: I don't assume it's the reason why you have the problem, but I think \Elastica\Query\Text() is depreciated and that you should use \Elastica\Query\Match() instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can try using Match() instead of Text(), but I don't think this will solve the issue (as multiple nesting is 'supposedly' supported by FOSElasticaBundle). Perhaps I will even try updating this bundle...
@CédricNirousset I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

FOSElasticaBundle uses the Elastica Library. So this should not be an issue of FOSElasticaBundle.

Have a Look at http://elastica.io/ for more Details about the Lib. In my experience,there is nothing you can not do with Elastica if it is supported by Elasticsearch. Even when there is no Mapper in Elastica, just use the Raw Array Query (http://elastica.io/example/raw-array-query.html) to build the desired Query.